# Temporary table in the Laravel - Base table or view not found: 1146 Table

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to store the data of my orders in the temp table so that I could pick it up after the payment is complete.

Issue I am facing now is that I am not able to find the table..

My understanding is that the Temp table is only available for particular session.

How do I extend it

My Orders Controller

```
/** Create Temp Table with the order name so that I could retreive it later*/

     Schema::create($order_name, function (Blueprint $table) {
                    $table->bigIncrements('id');
                    $table->string('service_request_id')->nullable();
                    $table->string('service_request_order_name')->nullable();
                    $table->string('created_service_request_order_name')->nullable();
                    $table->temporary();
                    $table->timestamps();
                });
    
                //Save the data in temp table
                $a =  DB::table($order_name)->insert(['service_request_id' => $service_request->id, 'service_request_order_name' => $old_order_name, 'created_service_request_order_name' => $order_name]);
    
                dd(
                     DB::table($order_name)->where('created_service_request_order_name', $order_name)->get()
                );
```

**Calling after the payment is success**

**Persist data controller**

```
public function persistData(){
dd(
                         DB::table($order_name)->where('created_service_request_order_name', $order_name)->get()
                    );
```

I am getting the below error

```
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'test.ORDER_001' doesn't exist
```

Comment: Temporary tables are session based. For example creating a temporary table could only be accessed via sessions and not the actual DB. Use Laravel DB's unprepared to directly interact with the database. Details: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-implement-temporary-table

Answer (score 0):

You cannot extend the existence of temporary tables beyond the lifespan of a mysql connection - this requirement is in stark contrast with the concept of temporary.

Either you store this data within the php session itself or you need to have a standard, non-temporary database table where you store the data.